# Getting date a contact was added to the address book in Swift 2, iOS 9

Tags: swift2, ios9, abaddressbook

In the previous version of Swift, I was able to get the date a contact was created in the phone using the `kABPersonCreationDateProperty` which came from the `AddressBook` framework.

Now that Apple has migrated to the `Contacts` framework, I don't see a way to retrieve the date a contact was created in their [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/CNContact_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CNContact/dates)

How can I retrieve the date a contact was created in Swift 2? Sample code would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Trying to use `kABPersonCreationDateProperty` gives me a warning: `kABPersonCreationDateProperty was deprecated in iOS 9.0` and if I try to run the code anyways I end up with a run-time error

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @harsh unfortunately not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is old, but just in case anyone needs it, I used the old fashioned way. There's no obvious way to record the date a contact is created but this technique circumvents the framework initially, in order to retrieve with the current locale time with `NSDate` then converting it to a String, and finally assigning to to `CNContactDatesKey` --which is the only available CNContactsLabel that categorically allows for non-birthday/anniversary dates assignment.

```
        let exampleContact = CNContact()

        let currentDate = NSDate()
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.FullStyle
        let finalConvertedDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(currentDate)
        exampleContact.setValue(finalConvertedDate, forKey: CNContactDatesKey)
```

...Then later, when you need to request it, you'd begin with the below process:

```
        let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: [CNContactIdentifierKey, CNContactDatesKey])
```

Any input is welcomed.